# .netcore 3 client certificate with HttpClient

Tags: rest, .net-core, x509certificate2

I have a .netcore 3 project (WorkerService Template) which sends JSON data to a REST endpoint. The requests are sent via a HttpClient and configured to use a client certificate which the server requires. The server response is always 200 and HTML characters. According to the server managers the request is redirected to the home page of the web server, because the client machine is being correctly handled with a specific user but no certificate is available. I am using the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddHttpClient("client").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => 
  {
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
    X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate(Configuration.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifier);
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    return handler;
  }
}
```

GetCertificate retrieves the certificate from the Certificate Store:

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string subjectIdentifier)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        var collection = store.Certificates;
        var certificates = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier, subjectIdentifier, true);
        foreach (var certificate in certificates)
        {
            if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(certificate.GetExpirationDateString()), DateTime.Now) >= 0)
            {

                Logger.LogInformation($"Loaded X.509 certificate {certificate.Subject} issued by {certificate.Issuer}, valid from {certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()} to {certificate.GetExpirationDateString()}");
                return certificate;
            }
        }

        Logger.LogError($"X.509 certificate not loaded: No valid certificate could be found.");
        return null;
    }
```

Code which sends a request:

```
public async Task<ResponseData> PostAsync<T>(string url, T dataToSend)
    {
        ResponseData result = null;
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = null;

        try
        {
            var errorHttp = false;
            HttpClient httpClient;
            using (httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("client)) // IHttpClientFactory initialized in ctor
            {
                HttpContent httpContent;
                using (httpContent = CreateJsonHttpContent(dataToSend, MediaType.ApplicationJson)) //build JSON from data
                {  
                    httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    result = BuildResponseData(httpResponseMessage); //writes response data in a class

                    if (httpResponseMessage?.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                    {
                        result.Content = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorHttp = true;
                    }

                    if (errorHttp)
                    {
                        var httpRequestException = new HttpRequestException($"The http request to {url} was not successful.");
                        Logger.LogError($"{httpRequestException.Message} : {httpRequestException.InnerException}");
                        Logger.LogError(httpRequestException.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"{socketException.Message} : {socketException.InnerException}");
            result = new ResponseData(socketException);
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"{wex.Message} : {wex.InnerException}");
            if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure || wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
            {
                Logger.LogError($"Cannot connect to the rest service : {WebExceptionStatus.Timeout}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            LogException(ref ex);
            result = new ResponseData(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            httpResponseMessage?.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The class which uses the PostAsync method is also registered in the ServiceCollection. Any ideas what could be wrong here? Could it also be that the certificate is not being handled correctly on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

My strong suspection is the misconfiguration on client (your) end. Your application reads for certificate from `LocalMachine` store. By default, only local administrator and `SYSTEM` account can read/use private keys for certificates installed in `LocalMachine` store.

Either, install the certificate in `CurrentUser` store of a user account under which the client application is running, or explicitly grant private key permissions to user account under which the client application is running. To do this:

1. Open Certificates MMC snap-in under `LocalMachine` context (*certlm.msc*)
2. Expand `Personal\Certificates`
3. Select desired certificate, right-click and then `Manage Private Keys` menu item.
4. Grant `Read` permissions to user account under which the client application is running.

In this case, you don't need to modify your code or move certificate between stores.

Comment: Hello, the user account under which the application is running already has the required permissions you mentioned.